# Angular Js Textarea Value not assigned through ng-model

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to this angular JS. I have one different issue.
Please anyone help. 
I have this code in html:

```
<textarea  ng-model="user_comments" md-maxlength="500" rows="5" required></textarea>
<input type="text" ng-model="text_comment">
<button ng-click="add_cmnt(text_comment,user_comments)">Added into textarea</button>
```

and Controller code is this:

```
$scope.add_cmnt = function(data1, data2){
  $scope.user_comments = data1+data2;
  console.log($scope.user_comments);
}
```

When i click this added into textarea button the text-comment was append into user_comments. But it's not work. I don't know why? Please anyone help.

Comment: If i didn't edit textarea and also give input to textbox, it will be added. But when i edited the textarea and give value it's not added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the model values without sending any parameters form the function.

Also covert to string before appending.

**`$scope.user_comments.toString() + $scope.text_comment.toString()`**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.add_cmnt = function(){
$scope.text_comment = $scope.text_comment ? $scope.text_comment : ''
$scope.user_comments = $scope.user_comments ? $scope.user_comments : ''
  $scope.user_comments = $scope.user_comments.toString() + ' ' + $scope.text_comment.toString()
$scope.text_comment = "";
  console.log($scope.user_comments);
}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<textarea  ng-model="user_comments" md-maxlength="500" rows="5" required></textarea>
<input type="text" ng-model="text_comment">
<button ng-click="add_cmnt()">Added into textarea</button>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Please run this snippet**

[Here is the fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/ywtsxnvx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I see your code working when i testing. But in you make some logical mistake. You can try this for your expected output.

In html

```
<textarea  ng-model="user_comments" md-maxlength="500" rows="5" required></textarea>
<input type="text" ng-model="text_comment">
<button ng-click="add_cmnt()">Added into textarea</button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.add_cmnt = function(data1, data2){
    $scope.user_comments = $scope.text_comment;
}
```